# Where can I find the Mac Template Project for Xamarin in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Since Xamarin is now free and open-source, I installed its Visual Studio integration.

Everything looks fine with one exception - I can't figure out what I need to do to create a Mac App (not an iOS app).

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You will need to use Xamarin Studio on OS-X for Xamarin.Mac development

Comment: https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq9

Comment: thanks, I know I can develop for mac using Xamarin Studio, my question was directed to Visual Studio

Comment: Nothing has changed in that regard, see the FAQ I linked, XS is required. VS w/Xamarin is still iOS only, no Mac support.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create Mac apps in Visual Studio.

See the requirements for developing for Xamarin.Mac [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/installation/#Required_Components).

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' answer from Xamarin posted on their forums is:

> Right now, we have no items on our public roadmap related to
>   integration with Visual Studio. As you noted, developing for OS X
>   requires tight integration with Xcode, and you'd need to be in front
>   of a Mac anyway to test.
>
> It has been an item of feedback we've received in the past, however.
>   Like all feedback, we'll consider it for future versions.
>
> Right now, you can use Xamarin Studio community edition (if the
>   community edition license applies to you) or use your Visual Studio
>   Professional/Enterprise license.

See:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63760/how-is-native-mac-going-to-be-handled-by-visual-studio-xamarin#latest